# How to export a cell in Messages console to PDF?

Tags: export, notebooks, cells

Using V12 on windows.

This is the problem. I am calling an external function (Rubi in this case, but it could be anything), which ends up printing a cell (image) to the Console. I simply want to capture this cell and export it to PDF file.

Even if I redirect the output to the current notebook, I can't use the command `Export["image.pdf", NotebookRead[PreviousCell[]]];` to do what I want, since the code which call the external function runs in a loop.

Is there a way to do the same as `Export["image.pdf", NotebookRead[PreviousCell[]]];` but to use the Message console as the notebook instead of the current notebook?

To make it more clear, here is a MWE.

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"PrintAction"}] = {"PrintToConsole"};

(*a function which prints an image to console*)
externalFunction[max_] := Print[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -max, max}]];

(*run a loop calling the function, and export its output*)
Do[
 externalFunction[n];

 (*need something like this*)
 (*Export["t.pdf",MessagesNotebookRead[PreviousCell[]]]; ??*) 
 ,
 {n, 1, 5}
 ]
```

[image]

Directing the Print to the current notebook does not work

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"PrintAction"}] = {"PrintToNotebook"};
externalFunction[max_] := Print[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -max, max}]];
Do[
 externalFunction[n];
 Export["t.pdf", NotebookRead[PreviousCell[]]];
 ,
 {n, 1, 5}
 ]
```

Since `PreviousCell[]` in the above is not what I want, it will read the cell before the actual loop itself.

Also this does not work

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"PrintAction"}] = {"PrintToNotebook"};
externalFunction[max_] := Print[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -max, max}]];
Do[
 Export["t.pdf", externalFunction[n]]
 ,
 {n, 1, 5}
 ]
```

I could not find a way to tell Mathematica to use the Messages console notebook as the notebook to the `PreviousCell[]`

What is the best way export a cell in Messages console to pdf file? It will be the last cell each time, as in the above example. This is done in a loop. Each iteration generates one Rubi cell in the Messages console and I need to capture that cell as an image.

### Appendix

If someone would like to try this with the actual Rubi output, here is a MWE

```
<< Rubi`
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"PrintAction"}] = {"PrintToConsole"};
Do [
 Steps[Int[x Sin[x], x]];
 (*save output in console to image, how?*)
 Steps[Int[x Cos[x], x]]
 (*save output in console to image, how?*)
 ,
 {n, 2}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you use `Last[Cells[MessagesNotebook[]]]` instead of `PreviousCell[]`? You wouldn't need to change the printing action then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your MWE the simplest solution is to dynamically redefine the `Print` function in the `Block` scope:

```
Do[
 Block[{Print := (Export[ToString[n] <> ".pdf", Echo@#, OverwriteTarget -> "KeepBoth"];) &},
  externalFunction[n];
  ]
 , {n, 1, 5}]
```

This will print every output in the evaluation notebook and immediately `Export` it after this. With this solution `externalFunction` may print any number of outputs which will be correctly saved as separate PDF files according to the new in version 12 `OverwriteTarget -> "KeepBoth"` option. If ***Rubi*** uses for printing other function than `Print` you can redefine it in the same way. If you have high requirements you may need to apply `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` and the Villegas-Gayley trick instead of simple `Block` showed above. But I don't think it is really necessary in your case.

Another approach (which more directly answers the question as it is stated in the title) is suggested in [the comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207809/how-to-export-a-cell-in-messages-console-to-pdf/207877#comment533735_207809) by [Gerli](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/8389/gerli):

```
Do[
 externalFunction[n];
 Export[ToString[n] <> ".pdf", Last[Cells[MessagesNotebook[]]]]
 , {n, 1, 5}]
```

It assumes that every evaluation of `externalFunction` results in printing of **exactly one** `Cell` in the `MessagesNotebook[]`.

Answer (score 1):

After some more time playing with this, I found this solution which seems to work. But I would be happy to accept a better solution.

Instead of using `PreviousCell`, I should use `NextCell`, but also have to delete each output cell as it is generated for this to work. So the MWE now is

```
 SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]

<< Rubi`

CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"PrintAction"}] = {"PrintToNotebook"};
Do [
 Steps[Int[x Sin[x], x]];
 Export["t1.pdf", NotebookRead[NextCell[]]];
 NotebookDelete[Cells[EvaluationNotebook[], GeneratedCell -> True]];

 Steps[Int[x Tan[x], x]];
 Export["t2.pdf", NotebookRead[NextCell[]]];
 NotebookDelete[Cells[EvaluationNotebook[], GeneratedCell -> True]];

 Steps[Int[x Log[x], x]];
 Export["t3.pdf", NotebookRead[NextCell[]]];
 NotebookDelete[Cells[EvaluationNotebook[], GeneratedCell -> True]];
 ,
 {n, 1}
 ]
```

This generated `1.pdf` and `2.pdf` and `3.pdf` all with the correct images for each call.

[image]